# How to convert a pyspark dataframe having a date-time format and keep only the date

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dataframe with one of the columns as "timestamp". It has data of the following format: `01/Jul/1995:00:00:01 -0400`.

Now I want to convert it to 01/Jul/1995 and also create an additional column that will have days(eg, Saturday, Sunday) of that corresponding date. How do I do the above?.

Comment: What are the datatypes of your dataframe? Can you show the output of `df.dtypes`?

Answer (score 1):

Create a sample dataframe

```
import datetime
from pyspark.sql import Row  
df_rows = {Row(id = 1, timestamp = datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 13)), 
           Row(id = 2, timestamp = datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 14))
          }
df = spark.createDataFrame(df_rows) 
df.show()
# +---+-------------------+
# | id|          timestamp|
# +---+-------------------+
# |  1|2019-12-13 09:00:00|
# |  2|2019-12-14 09:00:00|
# +---+-------------------+
```

Format timestamps

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, to_timestamp, date_format, dayofweek    

df.select(col("timestamp"), \
          date_format(col("timestamp"), "dd/MM/yyyy").alias("date"), \
          dayofweek(col("timestamp")).alias("day_n"), \
          date_format("timestamp", "E").alias("day_s")).show()
# +-------------------+----------+-----+-----+
# |          timestamp|      date|day_n|day_s|
# +-------------------+----------+-----+-----+
# |2019-12-13 09:00:00|13/12/2019|    6|  Fri|
# |2019-12-14 09:00:00|14/12/2019|    7|  Sat|
# +-------------------+----------+-----+-----+
```

using Pyspark's [`dayofweek`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.dayofweek.html) that returns the day of the week as a number and [`date_format`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.date_format.html) with [day-of-week pattern E](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html) to show the day of the week as a string.

I assumed that the dataframe contains timestamp datatypes. If the dataframe contains strings, you need to convert them to timestamps using `to_timestamp`.